# Hydrological model building for flooding analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology

I am recently studying the topic in investigating the features of river and to perform flooding analysis.

I got the elevation data, and I used the elevation data to generate streams in ArcGIS and I have studied the features of river such as the stream density, stream order, stream length in ArcHydro.

The first part of my study is finished, but I have no idea how to start with the flooding analysis.

Can I build a model in ArcGIS to perform the flooding analysis? I have read some papers related to my study and I found that the Curve number method may work in my study to get the discharge of the river. However, how can I compare the calculated discharge with the capacity of river(based on cross-section) to check whether flooding will occur?

Also, how can I work on Curve number method if only rainfall data and elevation data are given, as curve number method involves many calculation parameters, such as initial abstraction and infiltration rate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you:

Flood Hazard Analysis:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=775YPgO5LLE

How to model Coastal flooding in ArcGIS:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYpsSL4R6x0

Floodplain Analysis with ArcGIS Model Builder (ppt):
https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwjJv6So5cnKAhWBXQ8KHYxSAS8QFgg9MAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ce.utexas.edu%2Fprof%2Fmaidment%2Fgiswr2004%2Fnov23%2Frim.ppt&usg=AFQjCNFrMh30P2u0tdH7L3M-lzZZbBtUJw&sig2=9hKQ08fDZ6jjLzOKPRm64w&bvm=bv.112766941,d.ZWU&cad=rja